# Why is a question with no close votes in the Close Votes review queue?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

I just came to [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/underpaid-and-overworked-how-should-i-approach-my-boss) (on Workplace) in the Close Votes review queue, where I was asked if it should be closed as a duplicate of another question.  When I went to vote, however, I was surprised to find no trace of other close votes; usually you see how many votes for each reason have been cast.  I then went to the question page -- no close votes shown.

I suspect that somebody voted to close (kicking it into the queue) and then retracted the vote.  But shouldn't that have removed the question from the queue?  Or will it eventually and the answer is "because caching"?

Comment: Recommend Closure flag? Those bump questions into the queue too.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian, did you just...flag for closure? :-)  (You're right that this is a dupe and I'm about to vote, but at the moment mine'll be the first vote.)